# '503 Failed authentication on backend server: Unauthorized' when logging on to OWA

Tags: exchange-server, outlook-web-app

When logging on to OWA using a browser, receive a 503 error.  In the Fiddler trace will see a more detailed response status code:
`503 Failed authentication on backend server: Unauthorized`

On the Exchange Server, see the following **System** event log (intermittently):

```
Event 4 Security-Kerberos
The Kerberos client received a KRB_APP_ERR_MODIFIED error from the server exchangeserver$.  
The target name used was HTTP/exchangeserver.ad.root.  
This indicates that the target server failed to decrypt the ticket provided by the client.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope someone only receives this in a lab environment!

Here is a link to enable Kerberos logging, which could be helpful as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/enable-kerberos-event-logging

After enabling Kerberos logging, would see the KRB_APP_ERR_MODIFIED error more frequently, whereas before would not be logged each time a logon attempt occurred.

The issue here (in the lab) was that a duplicate SPN for the Exchange Server in question was added erroneously to another server, causing a duplicate.  This was due to trying to enable Kerberos delegation for a separate web application.

Although there could be a quicker way to do this, you can list the SPNs on each server to look for your erroneous exchangeserver record by running

```
setspn -l otherservername (this is a lower-case L)
```

And if you find that SPNs like http/exchangeserver or http/exchangeserver.ad.root are listed on another server (say 'otherservername'), you can carefully remove them by running

```
setspn -D http/exchangeserver otherservername
setspn -D http/exchangeserver.ad.root otherservername
```

I was able to logon to OWA immediately after the duplicate SPN was removed, without restarting any servers or services.

Answer (score 0):

Check, if the bindings for Exchange Backend website in IIS is correctly configured. You can check this by visiting IIS console in the server and open bindings for Backend website for 443 port. See, if the certificate is assigned well
[image]
Also, check, if the Default website's binding is correct. It should have thirdparty SSL certificate assigned or the self signed certificate
If any of the bindings are incorrect, fix it and restart IIS (iisrest from cmd prompt). Check again